# mysql complex update and replace

Tags: mysql, replace, inner-join, sql-update

I've got an interesting query that I wonder if anyone can help with?

Basically, I have three tables, Title, Attribute and Attribute_Value

Title contains a list of templates like 'Created on {Date} by {User} in {Category}' then in the Attribute table, I have rows that contain a definition of the parameters wrapped in curly brackets.

Then within the attribute_value table, I have the values.

The problem I have is that the Query doesn't seem to store the replace on each row until the query is complete, which means the row only receives the last update, incomplete.

```
update Title inner join Attribute_Value on Attribute_Value.GenericID = Title.CollectibleID and Attribute_Value.GenericType = 'collectible' inner join Attribute on Attribute.AttributeID = Attribute_Value.AttributeID set Title.Title = replace(Title.Title, concat('{', Attribute.Name, '}'), Attribute_Value.Value)
```

So basically, it will replace {Date} correctly, but then when it goes to replace {User}, {Date} is not the replaced value but still {Date} and same with {Category}. But when it's finished, the

Any idea's on how I can update the Title column with the values, whilst keeping the previously replaced values?

Cheers

Gav

Comment: You need to join to Attribute_value once for each value in the template - in this case 3 times.  Each join will cover one value.

Comment: @Martin, the attribute name/value and title are all completely generic. That'd be virtually impossible to handle.

Comment: Agreed. I think the simplest solution is to do the replacement in your application:  retrieve the template, extract the list of attributes, then retrieve the attributes, finally perform the substitutions.

Comment: @Martin, doing it by code might not be the best option. Reason being is that there are (at the moment) about 90k items in Title, about 150+k in attribute/attribute_value.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a [stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html) that uses a [cursor](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html) to update the attributes in `Title` one at a time.

Comment: Possibly, although that'd take forever to run :( It appears the row only updates when the whole query is complete, not when the row is complete.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I always go for correct code first, then worry about performance.

Answer (score 0):

If the list of attributes is static, I would probably go with subqueries and a nested SQL REPLACE(). Otherwise, write your own SQL function to iterate through all possible attribute names and make the substitutions.

Comment: Unfortunately not, the title and attribute name/values are completely generic. Thanks though ;)